# MySQL 5.7 Right join returns unexpected count

Tags: mysql, right-join

**Table tickets:**

This is a sales table & contains a 'ticket_type_id'. There are 4.9k rows (sales), e.g. ticket_type_id 1 has 1,451 rows, ticket_type_id 4 has 1,061 rows etc.

There are **18** values for ticket_type_id--1 through 10, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 30, 41.

(I.e. tickets for ticket_type_id e.g. 11 and 22 have not sold yet.)

**Table ticket_types:**

This is a master list of all ticket types & contains an 'id', enabling a join to the tickets table (referential integrity enforced).

There are **35** values--1 through 19, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44.

When I run a UNION I get a value of 53--correct.
When I run a UNION ALL, I get a value of 35--correct.

```sql
select distinct ticket_type_id from tickets t 
where t.user_id != 2 
and t.status = 'active'  -- 18 rows
    UNION
-- UNION ALL
select distinct id from ticket_types tt -- 35 rows
order by 1
```

When I run a RIGHT JOIN on the ticket_types table, I get **18** rows returned.
I.e. it returns only the matched values in the (left) tickets table.

```sql
-- RIGHT JOIN - doesn't work?
select t.ticket_type_id, tt.id
from tickets t
RIGHT OUTER join ticket_types tt
on t.ticket_type_id  = tt.id 
where t.user_id <> 2 and t.status = 'active' 
group by 1, 2
```

However, my expectation was that it would return **35** rows, the full set from the right (ticket_types) table.

I have also reversed the syntax and applied an equivalent LEFT join, getting the same results (18 rows, rather than 35).

Comment: Please add data sample, output you get and expected output.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: … See the [help] for more on [how to ask good questions](/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topic. See also the [tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2):

Your right join will include those rows with tt.id that does not match any t.ticket_type_id, with NULL values for all t columns.  But then you are excluding those with your `t.user_id = 2` and `t.status = 'active'` conditions, effectively changing your right join to an inner join.

If you wish to include only t rows with those conditions, but also include tt rows with no matching t row, you must move those conditions from `where` to the `on` clause:

```
select t.ticket_type_id, tt.id
from tickets t
RIGHT OUTER join ticket_types tt
on t.ticket_type_id  = tt.id 
and t.user_id = 2 and t.status = 'active' 
group by 1,2
```

Comment: but please don't use right joins, they are so much harder to read and follow than the equivalent left join